# Mongo db 4.2: replace field of an array item with the value of another field of the matched document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider a mongo collection containing the following documents:

```
{ name: "Enrico", age: 32, items: [{ type: "cat", color: "blue" }, { type: "dog", color: "red" }]},
{ name: "Francesca", age: 33, items: [{ type: "foo", color: "bar" }, { type: "hello", color: "world" }]},
{ name: "Mario", age: 40, items: [{ type: "cat", color: "green" }, { type: "dog", color: "white" }]}
```

I need to update al the documents where the `items` array contains a `cat`, by changing the value of the `color` property for the matching array item. The new value of the `color` property must be equal to the value of the `name` field of the matched document.

The desired result is the following:

```
{ name: "Enrico", age: 32, items: [{ type: "cat", color: "Enrico" }, { type: "dog", color: "red" }]},
{ name: "Francesca", age: 33, items: [{ type: "foo", color: "bar" }, { type: "hello", color: "world" }]},
{ name: "Mario", age: 40, items: [{ type: "cat", color: "Mario" }, { type: "dog", color: "white" }]}
```

By using the [$ update operator for arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) it's really easy to perform a similar update, by replacing the `color` property for the matching array item with a static value. For instance, the following update will replace the `color` property for the matching array item with the `"changed-color"` string literal:

```
db.people.updateMany(
    {"items.type": "cat"},
    {$set: {"items.$.color": "changed-color"}}
)
```

The problem here is that I would like to use **the value of another field of the matched document** (`name`) as the new value for the `color` property of the matched array item.

I know that since MongoDB 4.2 **it is possible to use an aggregation pipeline inside of an update query**, as documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#updatemany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline). By using the [$set aggregation pipeline operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) it is possible **to replace a document field with another value of the same document**, as documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#overwriting-an-existing-field).

So my attempt has been to combine the [$ update operator for arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)
with [the usage of an aggregation pipeline inside of an update query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#updatemany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline) and I ended up with the following query:

```
db.people.updateMany(
    {"items.type": "cat"},
    [
        {$set: {"items.$.color": "$name"}}
    ]
)
```

Unfortunately this query doesn't work: mongo db complains that the `$set` stage is invalid, because the `$` sign can't be used inside of a field path. It seems that the aggregation framework is not aware of the `$` update operator for arrays.

Is it possible to perform the update that I want by using a query ? Should I opt for a script instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$map` to iterate loop of items array, check condition if `type` is `cat` then return `color` from `$name` and merge objects using `$mergeObjects`,

```
db.people.updateMany(
  { "items.type": "cat" },
  [{
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.type", "cat"] },
                  { color: "$name" },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/prlk3rYvZMu)